# turning datagram into timeseries using set_index pandas

Tags: pandas, datagram

I have the following datagram:

```
        date      DP
0  1/31/1900  0.0357
1  2/28/1900  0.0362
2  3/31/1900  0.0371
3  4/30/1900  0.0379
4  5/31/1900  0.0410
```

I want to turn it into a timeseries, and I'm using set_index to do so. After running this line of code:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

I get the following timeseries:

```
               DP
date             
1/31/1900  0.0357
2/28/1900  0.0362
3/31/1900  0.0371
4/30/1900  0.0379
5/31/1900  0.0410
```

This is turning date into an index itself, which messes up my program later on when I concatenate datagrams via date. I know I can fix this manually, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here. As far as I know, I'm using the function correctly, and if I don't do it inplace pandas will make a new datagram and have the indexes be 0-n by default.

Comment: `s=df.set_index('date').DP`

Comment: Seems like it returns a datagram where the first collumn is the index and named date, but the second column has no header. What does the .DP do at the end of that?

Comment: That is series , date is the index , "date" is the index name , it only have one column data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
pd.Series(df.DP.values, pd.to_datetime(df.date))

date
1900-01-31    0.0357
1900-02-28    0.0362
1900-03-31    0.0371
1900-04-30    0.0379
1900-05-31    0.0410
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df.DP.set_axis(pd.to_datetime(df.date), inplace=False)

date
1900-01-31    0.0357
1900-02-28    0.0362
1900-03-31    0.0371
1900-04-30    0.0379
1900-05-31    0.0410
Name: DP, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**
@Wen's solution (will delete when he posts)

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.date)).DP

date
1900-01-31    0.0357
1900-02-28    0.0362
1900-03-31    0.0371
1900-04-30    0.0379
1900-05-31    0.0410
Name: DP, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Good solutions, the only issue I see being is that you can't merge Series, and later on I'm going to have to. Is there a workaround to this? I originally read my datagram from a CSV file, would it be better to read every date as an index?

Comment: Yes.  You can use `pd.concat([series1, series2, series3], axis=1)`

Comment: I was under the assumption merge and concat had the same behavior. I tried what you said precisely and ended up getting the same error:   all_indexes = [x._data.axes[i] for x in self.objs]
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_data'

Comment: That doesn't look like what I said.  I'd suggest posting another question so you have the opportunity to make your question clear.